# nlsLM application require initial parameters

Tags: r, regression

I'm new here and I need your help, i’m working on fitting water retention curve by van genuchten model and i’m trying to use the modified version of `nls`: `nlsLM` method from `minpack.lm` package in R, but I have a question about how to work with ‘start’ option, I mean, how to determine initial parameters of this model?, right now I set random starting values, and works well (no warnings or errors codes) but this is relative according dataset of the sample, so, my dilemma is, how to calculate the initial values ​​of the parameters of the van Genuchten model?, here my code:

```
sample <- data.frame(h = c(61,82,173,337,683,2356,7283,15300), 
                     theta_h = c(0.481,0.41,0.374,0.235,0.24,0.155,0.084,0.096))

mod <- nlsLM(theta_h ~ theta_r + (theta_s – theta_r)/(1 + (alpha*h)^n)^(1-1/n),
             data = sample,
             control = nls.lm.control(maxiter=200,options(warn=-1)),
             start = c(theta_s = 0.45, theta_r = 0.067, alpha = 0.02, n = 1.41),
             trace = TRUE)
```

appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: When working with water retention curves you have a-priori knowledge, e.g., depending on the texture and Corg-content you expect approximate parameter values. I would use a [pedotransfer function](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/234168627_Using_Pedotransfer_Functions_to_Estimate_the_van_Genuchten_Mualem_Soil_Hydraulic_Properties_A_Review) to estimate parameters and use these as starting values. A word of caution, although `nlsLM` is more robust than the default optimizer of `nls` you are more likely to suffer from bad fits, whereas `nls` would often simply return an error.

Comment: Hi Henrik, I am in agreement about to use of pedotransfer function to estimate parameters of van genuchten model, but i have knowlegde of measured water retention points so I need to find another method to take advantage of this with a precision not as bad as it could possibly offer me a pedotransfer function, maybe not. That depends on how widely is familiar with the physical and chemical characteristics of the soils studied for calibration of a particular pedotransfer function.

Comment: Finding out about Rosetta application by Schaap, I read that he suggests to fit water retention data with simplex or amoeba algorithm first where the objetive function is minimize the sum of the squared residuals...

Comment: I don't understand your comments. I suggest to use a PTF to get **starting values** for the fit.

Comment: As with all recursive algorithms for general nonlinear equation sets, there is no magic method for finding a useable starting point. You either need to have a good external way of making a guess, or you'll have to come up with some sort of fuzzy loop over initial guesses until one converges.

Comment: Finding out I decided at last to use average values for selected soil water retention and hydraulic conductivity parameters for 12 major soil textural groups according to Carsel and  Parrish PTF (1988). Thanks a lot for your help.